# Перенос коммитов между репозиториями

Tags: git

Имелись два независимых репозитория со своими историями: *A* и *B*. В какой-то момент было принято решение всё содержимое *B* поместить в *A*. Это было сделано путём обычного копирования файлов, т.о. в *A* появился один единственный коммит на это действие. Далее репозиторий *A* развивался, в частности менялись те части, которые раньше были в *B*.

Сейчас появилось осознание того, что не стоило объединять всё это дело в один репозиторий и нужно развивать отдельно.

Первая мысль: просто перенести все части (файлы), которые должны быть в *B*, из *A*. Таким образом опять появится один единственный коммит и можно жить дальше. Но хотелось бы всё же перенести и историю изменений этих файлов в репозиторий *B*.

В связи с этим вопрос: есть ли какой-то механизм, позволяющий переносить коммиты между несвязанными репозиториями? Вариант ручного копирования каждого отдельного состояния с соответствующим описанием не предлагать :) Хотелось бы, условно, задать диапазон коммитов из *A* и применить их к *B*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прежде всего, понадобится рабочая копия с двумя удаленными репозиториями. Пример получения такой копии:

```
git init
git remote add remote_a url_a
git remote add remote_b url_b
git fetch remote_a
git fetch remote_b
git checkout -b master remote_a/master
```

Для начала, нужно выделить в A изменения в файлах, которые на самом деле должны быть в B. Это делается командой [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), точная команда будет зависеть от того как вы собираетесь разделять файлы разных репозиториев. Скорее всего это будет что-то вроде:

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter path/to/b <начальный коммит>..HEAD
```

Теперь получившуюся ветку остается ребейзнуть на B и запушить:

```
git rebase <начальный коммит> --onto remote_b/master
git push remote_b HEAD:master
```

*Не проверял, могут быть опечатки.*

Comment: А нужно ли явно указывать диапазон коммитов? Вроде как есть опция `-all`. P.S. Я пока тоже не проверял. Завтра попробую уже.

Comment: @alexolut с ограниченным диапазоном будет быстрее работать :-)

Comment: так а будет ли он ограниченным, если начальный коммит действительно начальный?

Comment: @alexolut но ведь вы говорили что файлы из B были скопированы в уже существующий A? Значит, начальный коммит для В внутри А не является начальным для А.

Comment: ах, да, согласен! Правильно ли я понимаю, что фильтр исключит полностью коммиты, которые не затрагивают указанный путь, так и исключит лишние файлы из коммитов, в которых есть попадания пути?

Comment: @alexolut ну, так написано в документации

Comment: Пришлось немного повозиться из-за наличия разных веток и поразрешать конфликты при `rebase`, но всё получилось. Однако, некоторые коммиты продублировались и в диффах теперь проскакивает нечто вида `>>>>>>> Merge commit 'c99785032a9...`. Чего, конечно же, не было в исходных диффах.

Comment: @alexolut У меня вопрос: я правильно понимаю, что SHA1 коммитов будут другими? Если так, то я не вижу причин, чтобы не скопировать весь репозиторий в другую папку и тупо в rebase грохнуть ненужные строки. Ведь у них много общей истории, а потом кусок разошедшийся истории, который по факту нужно слегка почистить от ненужной.

Answer (score 1):

> Хотелось бы, условно, задать диапазон коммитов из A и применить их к B.

В принципе, это можно устроить комбинацией двух команд. Получить список всех фиксаций *от* и *до* командой `git rev-list`. Затем применить их командой `git cherry-pick`.

```
git cherry-pick `git rev-list --reverse <commit_hash_1>..<commit_hash_2>`
```

`<commit_hash_1>` и `<commit_hash_2>` следует заменить на хэши начальной и конченой фиксаций, которые задают ваш диапазон. Просим Git перечислять их в обратом порядке, от более ранней к поздней. (rev-list их просто выводит на стандартный поток). Это всё для того, чтобы `git cherry-pick` их правильно применаяла.

Указанную команду нужно выполнять в пределах целевого репозитория (B). Предполагается, что предварительно вы уже синхронизировались с репозиторием-источником (A). Например, так:

```
git fetch https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World
```

Comment: У вас, по-моему, получился `git rebase <commit_hash_1> <commit_hash_2> --onto HEAD` :)

Comment: Что-то я не понял. А где здесь работа с разными репозиториями?

Comment: @alexolut, предполагается, что предварительно вы уже синхронизировались с репозиторием-источником. Например, так: `git fetch URL/путь`.

Comment: Т.е. целевой - это `B`, а источник, стало быть, `A`?

Comment: @alexolut, да, именно так

Comment: Возможно, я что-то сделал не так, но `rev-list` не находит указанные мной коммиты.